# MessageBox Display Once

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I was wondering if there was a way to display a messagebox in WP8 just once i.e. on app opening.

I have the following code already, very basic.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
  MessageBox.Show("Hi");
}
```

However, this shows every time the app is opened.  I only want it to show the first time.

Is that possible?

Comment: You could remember in a bool if you showed the messagebox already. OR use the Loaded event which happens when you add the object to the visual tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this successfully in WP 8.0 Silverlight apps.  Create a reusable class, OneTimeDialog:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

namespace MyApp
{
    public static class OneTimeDialog
    {
        private static readonly IsolatedStorageSettings _settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        public static void Show(string uniqueKey, string title, string message)
        {
            if (_settings.Contains(uniqueKey)) return;

            MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButton.OK);

            _settings.Add(uniqueKey, true);
            _settings.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it anywhere in your app, like this:

```
OneTimeDialog.Show("WelcomeDialog", "Welcome", "Welcome to my app! You'll only see this once.")
```

Showing a "Hint" or "Welcome" dialog just once is helpful in lots of different types of apps, so I actually have the code above in a Portable Class Library so I can reference it from multiple projects.

Comment: Is there a way to format the text layout of the box i.e. paragraphs/bullet points etc?

Comment: Not the way you're doing it now, but have a look at the CustomMessageBox class in this nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit.  It offers a lot more options and I wouldn't be surprised if it could support that behavior.

Comment: Yep, looks like it definitely does support text formatting inside a CustomMessageBox: http://shawnoster.com/2012/10/welcome-custommessagebox-to-the-windows-phone-toolkit/

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to persist a state across sessions, an [isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.105).aspx) key-value pair is a good choice.  Just check before, and then update:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
  var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
  if (settings.ContainsKey("messageShown") && (bool)settings["messageShown"] == true)      
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Hi");
    settings["messageShown"] = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried that code however, ContainsKey returns the following error: 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings' does not contain a definition for 'ContainsKey' and no extension method 'ContainsKey' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I tried to use just 'Contains', the code runs but no message box is displayed then.

Comment: If it helps, I am using a Silverlight WP8.0 app.